# multivariate multiple regression with probabilities as the dependant variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multivariate-regression

I have a problem that involves multiple dependant variables, where each dependant variable is a probability and for each observation the probabilities sum to 1.0. I also have a range of independent variables for each observation. I would like to model the dependant variables. This model need be a traditional "statistical" model, or it could come from the area of machine learning. My data could look like:

```
OBS   Y1   Y2   Y3   Y4    X1   X2   X3
  1  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  12.1  8.2  7.8
  2  0.7  0.0  0.1  0.2   8.1  1.2  3.2
  3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.7   7.3  1.5  7.2
  4  0.2  0.2  0.3  0.3   1.5  4.6  5.6
...
```

The purpose is mainly predictive, ie given a set of values for X1, X2 and X3, what is the prediction for Y1, Y2, Y3 and Y4 subject to the constraint that Y1+Y2+Y3+Y4=1.0 and 0.0 <= Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4 <= 1.0. A way to interpret the actual coefficients would be nice also, but it is prediction rather than interpretation here.

I know that in R it is quite easy to model in this form by providing multiple Y variates to the left hand side of the '~'. But I don't know how to enforce a constraint or a knowledge that the Y's are all between 0.0 and 1.0 and must sum to 1.0. Thanks.

Comment: From traditional statistical methods, you could always use a multinomial logistic regression here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression. You can find an R tutorial on this on UCLA's IDRE website:  https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/.  Keep in mind, this is only one statistical approach.  There are many different types of approaches  you could use.

Also, a similar question was asked here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178738/can-i-set-up-multiple-probability-models-that-sum-to-1

Comment: Could you explain how these probabilities are determined?  Because a probability is a hypothetical construct, usually what one has is *estimates* of probabilities from data, often as proportions.  That detail is crucial, because the certainty of the estimates plays a role in prediction as well as assessing the precision of the prediction.

Comment: The probabilities are based on how the population of an area is composed. For example a city, and the population of the city falls into five ethnic groups.Thus I have a proporation that are White; proportion that are Mixed; ...; proportion that are "Other". These five proportions sum to 1.0. The outcome for each area is not nominal.

Comment: I think this "answers" my question [modelling-time-series-of-percentages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/380279/modelling-time-series-of-percentages), but if anyone has anything else to add ...